# TNumberBox ValueType = Float Setting not working

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Delphi 10.1 Berlin, I have a Tnumberbox in a Multi-Device Unit, the Decimal is set to 2 and the Valuetype to Float but I cannot get the decimal places to show and it actually rounds of any input to the whole number.  I have tried using the different platforms but all give the same result.   Can anyone shed some light on this as it is frustrating and not working the way it should.   I also tried to set the values onCreate to create a value to 1.50 and then 0.00 but still no decimal places.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, the expected result and what you're actually getting.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. If I set properties (note, it is `DecimalDigits`, not `Decimal`) as you describe and the value 3.14, that is exactly what it displays in runtime. I also added another `TNumberBox` with `DecimalDigits` set to 5, and assigned its value at runtime `NumberBox2.Value := 7 * NumberBox1.Value;` and it shows 21.98000 as expected. **Please, provide exact steps to reproduce the problem!**

Comment: Oh, and by the way, Welcome to SO! Please read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question, especially [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and all linked docs.

Comment: You may want to set `HorzIncrement` and `VertIncrement` both to zero (default are 1 and 5 respectively) to prevent unexpected changes to the values due to mouse movements. Perhaps this was the cause of your problem, although your description gives no hint of that.

Comment: Thank you Tom and excuse my rookie mistakes I will take the time to read these articles.    There was not much code to post as I narrowed it down creating a new unit and only added TNumerbox.  Now I decided to reopen and clean and build again and now it works.    Cant explain what happened.   I also tried to change the Vertical and Horizontal and that works as it should.  Yes I know its DecimalDigits. I abbreviated. Thanks for the welcome, looking forward to participating further on SO.

Comment: Tom if you set the value to 0 or 0.00 either at design or runtime you get 0 without the decimal places.   Isnt setting this to Float and two decimals supposed to show 0.00 regardless or 100.00.  I am getting 0 or 100 no decimals ?

Comment: A hint: If you address a comment to a person (other than asker or answerer) with the @ character like in @Eddie (yes you can abbreviate the name), the adressee will get a notification about your message. Yes, it seems true that decimals are not shown if zero. But if only one meaningful decimal digit then all (also following zeros) are shown. I don't know why. The help emphasizes the control as a *user input control*, maybe that is why? Anyway, I could not repeat your claim of rounding **any input** to whole numbers. Only fully expected rounding like 1.9999999 becoming 2.